# Distribute matrix by unique id column to new matrices

Tags: r, vector, matrix

Say in R, you have a matrix (a small example) such that it looks like

```
      id  A  B  C
1     IN  5 12  3
2     DT  4 11  6
3     DT  7 11  6
4     GG  2  1  3
5     GG  4 11  5
6     IN  4  2  5
```

Here we see that there are 3 groups of ids (`IN`, `DT`, `GG`) and thus in this case (in my real case its 18) I need 3 new matrices (or a class with 3 matrices?).

The reason I want to do separate them and do separate down-the-line things to happen. thanks

if it helps, there is a vector of 'ids' that can be used; here again that would be:

```
c("IN", "DT", "GG")
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a `matrix` and not a `data.frame`?

Comment: it can be anything.... cant it... just... as.matrix() as.data.frame() .. no?

Comment: Well, if it was a matrix, then everything would be a 'character'. Also, different techniques would be used to split the two types.

Comment: thats great, and the best one is.... to have x data type and do ....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally nice to post your data in a format we can quickly use (use `dput` on your object so we can just cut and paste), I read in your data here:

```
df<-(read.table(textConnection('       id A  B  C
1     IN  5 12  3
2     DT  4 11  6
3     DT  7 11  6
4     GG  2  1  3
5     GG  4 11  5
6     IN  4  2  5'),header=TRUE))
```

If it is a `data.frame`, you can get a nice list with:

```
split(df,df$id)
# $DT
#   id A  B C
# 2 DT 4 11 6
# 3 DT 7 11 6
# 
# $GG
#   id A  B C
# 4 GG 2  1 3
# 5 GG 4 11 5
# 
# $IN
#   id A  B C
# 1 IN 5 12 3
# 6 IN 4  2 5
```

But if it is a matrix, you could do:

```
df.matrix<-as.matrix(df)
lapply(unique(df[,'id']),function(x) df.matrix[df.matrix[,'id']==x,])
```

Comment: thank you, the data frame method proved to be better for my use.